# How to set border's thickness in percentages?

Tags: css

How to set border-width of an element in percentages? I tried the syntax

```
border-width:10%;
```

But it doesn't work.

The reason I want to set `border-width` in percentages is I have an element with `width: 80%;` and `height: 80%;`, and I want the element to cover the whole browser window, so I want to set all borders 10%. I am not doing this with the two elements method, in which one would be positioned behind the other and act as the border, because the element's background is transparent, and positioning an element behind it would affect it's transparency.

I know this can be done via JavaScript, but I am looking for an CSS only method, if possible at all.

Comment: `border-width` doesn't support percentage as value. You can use em, px, ex etc. But why you want to set a `border-width` of 10%?

Comment: Percentage of what? This is essential for finding a workaround. The simple approach is obviously wrong, since percentages are not allowed there. You will probably need to set up an auxiliary element and play with backgrounds, but the details depend on the answer to the question “percentage of what?”

Comment: percentage of screen. the element is absolutely positioned, so percentage of screen

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Is there a case when percentage is referring to anything else than positioned container? Why the question then?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha, are you sure you mean the screen (width), not the window width?

Comment: Why use a percentage? So that when an element size changes because of a media query or screen size change, the border is also resized to be proportional to the element is surrounds. Otherwise, an element that becomes small when someone resizes their window might end up with a border that is huge compared to the element itself.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### Border doesn't support percentage... but it's still possible...

As others have pointed to [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-width-properties), percentages aren't supported on borders:

```
'border-top-width',
'border-right-width',
'border-bottom-width',
'border-left-width'
  Value:          <border-width> | inherit
  Initial:        medium
  Applies to:     all elements
  Inherited:      no
  Percentages:    N/A
  Media:          visual
  Computed value: absolute length; '0' if the border style is 'none' or 'hidden'
```

As you can [see](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-width-properties) it says **Percentages: N/A**.

### Non-scripted solution

You can simulate your percentage borders with a wrapper element where you would:

1. set wrapper element's `background-color` to your desired border colour
2. set wrapper element's `padding` in percentages (because they're supported)
3. set your elements `background-color` to white (or whatever it needs to be)

This would somehow simulate your percentage borders. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/We3MH/) of an element with 25% width side *borders* that uses this technique.

HTML used in the example

```css
.faux-borders {
    background-color: #f00;
    padding: 1px 25%; /* set padding to simulate border */
}
.content {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="faux-borders">
    <div class="content">
        This is the element to have percentage borders.
    </div>
</div>
```

**Issue:** You have to be aware that this will be much more complicated when your element has some complex background applied to it... Especially if that background is inherited from ancestor DOM hierarchy. But if your UI is simple enough, you can do it this way.

### Scripted solution

[@BoltClock mentioned scripted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13474782/75642) where you can programmaticaly calculate border width according to element size.

[This is such an example](http://jsfiddle.net/GpfMu/) with extremely simple script using jQuery.

```js
var el = $(".content");
var w = el.width() / 4 | 0; // calculate & trim decimals
el.css("border-width", "1px " + w + "px");
```

```css
.content { border: 1px solid #f00; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
    This is the element to have percentage borders.
</div>
```

But you have to be aware that you will have to **adjust** border width every time your **container size changes** (i.e. browser window resize). My first workaround with wrapper element seems much simpler because it will automatically adjust width in these situations.

The positive side of scripted solution is that it doesn't suffer from background problems mentioned in my previous non-scripted solution.

Comment: problem with non-scripted solution: `set your elements background-color to white (or whatever it needs to be)` It is semi-transparent so as to show the background image, using another element will destroy the purpose.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha: I've pointed out this issue in my answer anyway. That's why I also provided alternative *scripted* solution which doesn't suffer from this. But depending on the background it could still be possible to resolve this issue **without** scripting. But this hugely depends on the individual situation.

Comment: The non-scripted solution will not work if you need transparency on the bordered content (since the wrapper background will show through).

Comment: Another issue with the non-scripted solution: different *border colors* aren't possible (e.g. `border-left-color: green`)

Comment: I had somehow thought about a solution like yours before. I didn't know if the div with background and padding with another div inside alternative was that good. Now it seems to validate it. In my case, it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Another issue with using background color as a border is that printers by default usually don't print any background colors.  The user typically has to turn this back on manually at print time.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! This really helped to me think from a different perspective.

Comment: `border-width` not support percent value `%`, just using `em` instead of `%`

Answer (score 45):

**You can also use**

```
border-left: 9vw solid #F5E5D6;
border-right: 9vw solid #F5E5D6;
```

OR

```
border: 9vw solid #F5E5D6;
```

Comment: This is only solution on here that is remotely reasonable.

Comment: This is not what OP asked though. OP wants a border in the current element percentage, not in viewport percentage.

Comment: @autra, that's exactly what OP asked: _"I want the element to cover the whole browser window"._

Comment: Oh right, ok. It's because OP actually asked the wrong question about their issue, already supposing setting border in percent was the only solution to their particular problem. I was fooled by that, sorry :-)

Comment: it's the best answer !

Answer (score 27):

So this is an older question, but for those still looking for an answer, the CSS property Box-Sizing is priceless here:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit  */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko         */
box-sizing: border-box;
```

It means that you can set the width of the Div to a percentage, and any border you add to the div will be included within that percentage. So, for example, the following would add the 1px border to the inside of the width of the div:

```
div { box-sizing:border-box; width:50%; border-right:1px solid #000; }
```

If you'd like more info: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: This is useful when you don't care about the border-width and only about covering the full screen, but not otherwise.

Comment: that's what he was asking for originally - covering the whole screen, but including a width of a border. You can change the border width here to any pixel amount and it won't throw off your div percentage widths.

Comment: I was trying to say that this solution addresses one of the problems in the original question, that is covering the whole screen without overflow. But this is not helpful when you want to set your border in terms of percentage of screen width/height

Comment: This is a great solution and approach, thanks Kimberly! Really helped shading the outside of an element where the inside was transparent.

Answer (score 5):

You can use em for percentage instead of pixels,

Example:

```
border:10PX dotted #c1a9ff; /* In Pixels */
border:0.75em dotted #c1a9ff; /* Exact same as above in Percentage */
```

Comment: em is a percentage, but it is relative to the font size, not the height or width of the containing box/element.

Comment: Em rounds to full pixels at least for me.

Answer (score 4):

Percentage values are not applicable to `border-width` in CSS. This is listed in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-width-properties).

You will need to use JavaScript to calculate the percentage of the element's width or whatever length quantity you need, and apply the result in `px` or similar to the element's borders.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Exactly :) I felt I needed to clarify that in my answer so I've edited it now...

Comment: @Robert: Maybe I'll give it a try... and if necessary I'll roll it back.

Answer (score 4):

[Modern browsers support vh and vw units](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh), which are a percentage of the window viewport.

So you can have pure CSS borders as a percentage of the window size:

```
border: 5vw solid red;
```

Try [this example](https://jsbin.com/wekodi/) and change window width; the border will change thickness as the window changes size. `box-sizing: border-box;` may be useful too.

Answer (score 4):

[As of 2023] I solved this with container query units (`cqmin` in particular)

```css
border: 0.5cqmin solid black;
```

This sets the border to 0.5% of the width or height of the container (whichever is smaller).

- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries
- W3C Draft: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-contain-3/#container-lengths
- CanIUse: https://caniuse.com/css-container-query-units

> `cqmin`: The smaller value of either cqi or cqb
> https://www.w3.org/TR/css-contain-3/#container-lengths
>
> `cqb`: A measurement in the block dimension: refers to the physical height (vertical dimension) in horizontal writing modes, and to the physical width (horizontal dimension) in vertical writing modes.
> https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-4/#block-size
>
> `cqi`: A measurement in the inline dimension: refers to the physical width (horizontal dimension) in horizontal writing modes, and to the physical height (vertical dimension) in vertical writing modes.
> https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-4/#inline-size

Answer (score 2):

**Box Sizing**
set the box sizing to border box `box-sizing: border-box;` and set the width to 100% and a fixed width for the border then add a min-width so for a small screen the border won't overtake the whole screen

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom border using a span. Make a span with a class (Specifying the direction in which the border is going) and an id:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="mdiv">
            <span class="VerticalBorder" id="Span1"></span>
            <header class="mheader">
                <span class="HorizontalBorder" id="Span2"></span>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, go to you CSS and set the class to `position:absolute`, `height:100%` (For Vertical Borders), `width:100%` (For Horizontal Borders), `margin:0%` and `background-color:#000000;`. Add everthing else that is necessary:

```
body{
    margin:0%;
}

div.mdiv{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    margin:0%;
}

header.mheader{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:20%; /* You can set this to whatever. I will use 20 for easier calculations. You don't need a header. I'm using it to show you the difference. */
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    margin:0%;
}

span.HorizontalBorder{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin:0%;
    background-color:#000000;
}

span.VerticalBorder{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    margin:0%;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

Then set the id that corresponds to `class="VerticalBorder"` to `top:0%;`, `left:0%;`, `width:1%;` (Since the width of the mdiv is equal to the width of the mheader at 100%, the width will be 100% of what you set it. If you set the width to 1% the border will be 1% of the window's width). Set the id that corresponds to the `class="HorizontalBorder"` to `top:99%` (Since it's in a header container the top refers to the position it is in according to the header. This + the height should add up to 100% if you want it to reach the bottom), `left:0%;` and `height:1%`(Since the height of the mdiv is 5 times greater than the mheader height [100% = 100, 20% = 20, 100/20 = 5], the height will be 20% of what you set it. If you set the height to 1% the border will be .2% of the window's height). Here is how it will look:

```
span#Span1{
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    width:.4%;
}
span#Span2{
    top:99%;
    left:0%;
    width:1%;
}
```

DISCLAIMER: If you resize the window to a small enough size, the borders will disappear. A solution would be to cap of the size of the border if the window is resized to a certain point. Here is what I did:

```
window.addEventListener("load", Loaded);

function Loaded() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", Resized);

  function Resized() {
    var WindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var WindowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var Span1 = document.getElementById("Span1");
    var Span2 = document.getElementById("Span2");
    if (WindowWidth <= 800) {
      Span1.style.width = .4;
    }
    if (WindowHeight <= 600) {
      Span2.style.height = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

If you did everything right, it should look like how it is in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/umhgkvq8/12/
For some odd reason, the the border will disappear in jsfiddle but not if you launch it to a browser.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [calc() specification](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp). Here is an example of usage:

```
border-right:1px solid;
border-left:1px solid;
width:calc(100% - 2px);
```