# Formatting of navigation div

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to sort out my navigation div. I am having a whole variety of problems and I have been trying to sort them out for hours. I am a rookie programmer so please forgive me.

First here is a snap of my css

```
#navigation { 
background: rgba(109, 183, 229, 1);
display: block; 
position: static;
height: 40px;
width: 96%; 
padding: 1% 2% 0% 2%;
clear: both;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #31679a;
border: 0% 0% 1% 0%;}
```

1. The border isn't behaving, because it is displaying it all the way around even though I clearly specify 0% for 3 sides. (SOLVED: changed to border-width, and changed % to px as border doesn't allow %)
2. Next I can't seem to center it perfectly in the middle. I've tried all sorts of things, but I can't seem to get it to function properly. (SOLVED: Magesh and Adam both provided good solutions to this problem, however Adam's achieved my desired results much easier)
3. I can't seem to get it to not be squeezed when resizing the window. This used to work, but after a couple of changes, it has stopped. I want it to disappear when the width is too small.

I feel like this will be a silly question, and the answer will be a small % here and there I have overlooked. But it is becoming very frustrating. (You may also notice the main body is overflowing over the border I've put at the bottom - no idea why). I will be extremely greatful for any help here.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add. View it here: [www.dweeman.com/eb/sitetemplate.html](http://www.dweeman.com/eb/sitetemplate.html)

EDIT: I've created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw2s8/) for you

Comment: Could you add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Post your HTML code as well please

Comment: to solve the border problem: change border: ... to "border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px" (thanks to Liam for correcting me)

Comment: [Borders do not support percentages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages)

Comment: Ah okay, so border-width + px solves that issue. Thank you.

Comment: the problem is now, your borders are static but everything else is percentage. I don't think your going to achieve what you want to achieve in this manner.

Comment: Because I only want it at the bottom, would that be an issue? I am mostly working in %s with width, so with something that adds a static height is that an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer is for your centering problem

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
    display:table;
    width:100%;   /*This ensures that the element covers the entire width*/
    text-align:center;   /*To center the text*/
    list-style:none;   /*Remove the bullets*/
    margin:0;   /*Remove margins*/
    padding:0;   /*Remove extra padding*/
}
ul li{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

See here for example -> [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/wEHch/)

Warning : This is just for example, you could style this better.

> **Direct Solution:** Replace this code with the code on your website,It'll work perfectly :)

```
#ddmenu {
display: table;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background: #31679a transparent;
border-radius: 0.125em;
cursor: pointer;
color: #8aa8bd;
}
#ddmenu li{ 
display: table-cell;
font-size: 1.20em;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
border-right: 0px solid #dae0e5;
}
#ddmenu li a {
display: block;
padding: 0 0.750em;
line-height: 1.40em;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
color: #31679a;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

Comment: Will this work for my setup though? The actual menu content is within the div #ddmenu, which is contained in the #navigation div, which is what has the light blue background is where I want it centered. This looks like it would center the items within the #ddmenu, which wouldn't solve where #ddmenu is sitting.

Comment: Yes it will work in all cases.
You can try resizing the fiddle's output window and you can see that it'll automatically get adjusted to the width of the window!

Comment: try the direct solution

Comment: Is the display table cell supposed to be outside the brackets?

Comment: Nope sorry, a typo ! Check it out :)

Comment: Note that I have replaced complex styling with simple solutions.Forgive me for editing it out

Comment: Okay so that works a treat. Except they are way too spaced out. Adam Hughes below has given a much quicker fix, I'm sorry to say!

Comment: No problem at all dude.. Usually the navigation stretches to the complete viewport's width :) My pleasure though

Comment: So if I used your code, and set a viewport width, it would restrain it? Also, do you know why it gets squeezed when I resize my window smaller, rather than just disappearing?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the ***width:100%*** from the **#ddmenu** and then put a ***text-align:center*** on **#navigation** that should centre the menu.

To make it stop scaling down at a certain width you can use a min-width

```
#navigation {
    min-width:700px;
}
```

To make it completely disappear at a certain width you can use a media query in your css. Insert it at the end of your main css.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    #navigation { 
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, that was simple. But I still have the issue when you resize it, it eventually gets squeezed rather than disappearing.

Comment: I've added a media query to the answer above. That should make it disappear

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Have I done it wrong? I've updated my website to show it. Also, in this process, my header now overflows again.

Comment: You want to put Media Queries after all your main css content. The purpose of it is to overwrite your previous styles

Comment: Hmm, see this makes it actually disappear altogether, rather than disappearing out the side of the screen, depending on the size. 

Say you resize this website (stack overflow), when it gets to a certain width, it starts to slowly go out of view, rather that just completely disappearing.

Comment: Ah sorry. Completely misunderstood. You need to set a min-width and then that will prevent to from getting too small. Remove the Media Query from before.

Comment: why dont you lower the font size?!??

Comment: Will this work okay if I'm using percentages? I have to go to bed now,  so I'll have to come back to this tomorrow. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Yeah. The browser will detect the pixel width and stop it from going under that size. Above that the 100% width will kick in again

Comment: This hasn't seemed to work. It is still squeezing at certain widths

Comment: The min-width needs to be a pixel size not a percentage.