# How can I use percents in `border-*` properties?

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I have code which uses the Twitter Bootstrap 3, `nav` with `right-arrow`, which I created using `border-*` properties. But if I use very long text in `right-arrow`, it does not expand, and if I use percents, the code will not work...

Example on **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W623k/)**

[image]

```css
.custom-nav-stacked>li>a {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.custom-nav-stacked>li.active>a:after,
.custom-nav-stacked>li.active>a:hover:after,
.custom-nav-stacked>li.active>a:focus:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -19px;
  /*margin-left: -1px;*/
  border-top: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 13px solid #428bca;
  border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top:  20px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="width: 300px /* width there only for pretty demo */">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked custom-nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">A long long text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Small text</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">A long long long long long long long long long text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Small text 111</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example on **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W623k/)**

How can I make the triangle responsive based on the amount of text?

Comment: duplicate off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages

Comment: that's a quite trivial task with a bit of js/jq

Comment: Side note: the `a:hover` and `a:focus` using the same CSS is not needed as the C in CSS stands for *Cascading*, which means the styles will apply to all states of the element by default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only *relative* unit (meaning reactive to something else) that `border` can use is the `vh` and `vw` units. As a result, `border` can only be responsively sized when the element it is on is *also* sized relative to the viewport. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/W623k/3/)

As a result, what you're trying to do with CSS is not currently possible because if you set the height and border with viewport units then they will not respond to the text content. You'd have to give a class to the ones of varying height, thus defeat the purpose of relative sizing anyway.

However, this is pretty easy to do using javascript. You just need to iterate through the relevant elements, calculate the height of the element, divide that by 2 and make that the `border-top` and `border-bottom`, then make a proportion of that the `border-left`. [**Demo of that**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/W623k/4/)

```
/* JS */
var actives = document.getElementsByClassName("active"),
    triangles = document.getElementsByClassName("triangle");

for(var i = 0, l = actives.length; i < l; i++) {
    triangles[i].style.borderTopWidth = actives[i].clientHeight / 2 + "px";
    triangles[i].style.borderBottomWidth = actives[i].clientHeight / 2 + "px";
    triangles[i].style.borderLeftWidth = actives[i].clientHeight / 3 + "px";
    triangles[i].style.marginTop = - actives[i].clientHeight / 2 + "px";
}

/* CSS */
li.active .triangle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%; /* Position it to the right */
    top: 50%;
    border-color:transparent; /* Make all other sides transparent */
    border-left-color:#428bca; /* Add color to the side that matters */
    border-style:solid; /* This property is necessary to make it show */
}
```

Actual (meaning in the DOM) elements are suggested as opposed to pseudo elements using the javascript approach because they are much easier to access using the DOM. If you do end up using pseudo elements, you will need to change the actual stylesheets which is [more difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/2065702)