# Create bottom responsive arrow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-shapes

I need to create grid with a down arrow. See the image below:

[image: example]

The problem is that the div has a variable width because of `.col-xs-3`. How can I give the arrow (`:after` element) the appropriate width so that it will still be responsive?

**My CSS**:

```css
.grid-arrow::after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 47px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 47px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid rgb(173, 173, 173);
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 50%; */
    margin-top: -37px;
    /* margin-left: 1px; */
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

**My HTML**:

```html
<div class="col-xs-3 advantage grid-arrow">
    <div>
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use a background image aligned to the bottom instead? (and leave a bottom padding large enough) or does it have to be done strictly in CSS?

Comment: I really prefer css if there is good solution..

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360411/responsive-css-triangle-with-percents-width

Comment: JsFiddle of OP's case: http://jsfiddle.net/fhzv3mmf/

Comment: I've made a working fiddle based on @ochi's recommendation link: http://jsfiddle.net/fhzv3mmf/2/

If it is fine for you, this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @ochi, there is already a [solution that might work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25360673/1064325).

Bringing it back to your code, it would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 advantage grid-arrow">
    <div>
        Some text.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-arrow {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-top:300px solid #fff;
    top:-300px;
}
.grid-arrow::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    width:57.7%;
    z-index:-1;

    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
}
```

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhzv3mmf/2/).