# CSS Responsive Triangle Width

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Simple question really, I want to know how I would make a triangles width (made in css with the below code) equal to the page width so when the browser resizes so does the triangle.

**My Code, So far**

```
.triangle {
    color: crimson;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 30%;
    border-top: 100px solid crimson;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360411/responsive-css-triangle-with-percents-width

Comment: You set the width to 0. Assuming the tag with the class `triangle` is a child of body, I'd try with `width: 100%;`.

Comment: @cezar the whole point of the construct is that the element has 0 width as it gets its looks from the border.

Comment: tried width 100% it just messes up the triangle

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Thanks for clarifying! I didn't pay attention while reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.triangle {
    color: crimson;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 30%;
    border-top: 100px solid crimson;
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent; /* check border size here! */
    border-right: 50vw solid transparent; /* and here! */
}
```

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp9fLt7y/).

[Read more on CSS3 vh/vw units](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units).

[Browser support is not an issue](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: I would like to point something that I'm not catching. If `width` property is equal to `0`, how does it gets the full width of the window/parent? Just something I'm wondering since I saw this post!

Comment: `width: 0` is set to the triangle and not the window/viewport. So it will work.

Comment: @Cheshire the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) defaults to that `width` specifies the size of the content part of the element, excluding borders and padding. Another solution to the problem in this case would have been to specifiy `width:100%` and `box-sizing:border-box` actually, same effect.