# How to create responsive triangle as right border?

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design, css-shapes

I am trying to make a responsive triangle for one border, which will be visible only on `hover`. I tried the below code but it doesn't work because it uses static `border-width`. When I have one-string (single line) link it's perfect, but when strings more (more than one line), it's failing.

[Example here](http://codepen.io/ostinred/pen/YXEEON)

**Code here:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS here:**

```
ul{
  width:120px;
  li{
    list-style-type: none;
    a{
      position:relative;
      display:block;
      padding:10px;
      color:#00f;
      text-decoration: none;
      &:hover{
        color:#fff;
        background:#00f;
        &:after{
          content:'';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: -5px;
          height: 0;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 19px 0 19px 11px;
          border-color: #fff #fff #fff #00f;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The last link fails. Using an image or picture is not a solution for the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive CSS triangle with percents width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360411/responsive-css-triangle-with-percents-width)

Comment: While the thread linked above is very close to this one, the same approach cannot be adopted here because there the triangle size is proportional to the `width` of the parent element (and hence percentage `padding` can be used to preserve aspect ratio) whereas here it has to be proportional to the `height` of the parent element (percentage `padding` is always calculated in relation to `width`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the `border` triangle method to create the triangles here because the `height` of your element is dynamic. Instead you could use any of the following alternatives:

**Inline SVG + Clip Path:** <sup>Recommended</sup>

You can make use of inline SVG and `clip-path` to produce the bar with a triangle effect. The `clip-path` is applied only while hovering on the `a` tag  and so the normal state remains unaffected. The [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) for this is much better than the CSS equivalent.

```css
ul {
  width: 120px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-shape);
  -moz-clip-path: url(#clip-shape);
  clip-path: url(#clip-shape);
  background: crimson;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0,0 0.8,0 1,0.5 0.8,1 0,1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Transforms:**

You can use `transform: rotate(45deg)` on a pseudo-element to produce the triangle and then position it at the end of the `a` to produce the shape. The parent has a `overflow: hidden` setting to cut out the portions of the triangle that is not required to be displayed.

```css
ul {
  width: 120px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
  background-color: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
a:hover {
  background: crimson;
  background-clip: content-box;
  color: beige;
}
```

```html
<!-- Library included just to avoid prefixes so that users with older browser can view -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Alternately, you could use two pseudo-elements with a `transform: skew(45deg)` applied to them (in opposite directions) to get the triangle shape. Here also the parent has `overflow: hidden` setting.

```css
ul {
  width: 120px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a:before,
a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: -15%;
  z-index: -1;
}
a:before {
  top: 0px;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
a:after {
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
a:hover:after,
a:hover:before {
  background: crimson;
}
a:hover{
  color: beige;
}
```

```html
<!-- Library included just to avoid prefixes so that users with older browser can view -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

These are probably the **closest to pure CSS solutions with good browser support**. However, they still needs some tweaking of the properties like `padding-right` (for `rotate` method) and `left` (for `skew` method) etc when the height increases further and hence is not recommended.

---

**CSS Clip Path:**

You can make use of a polygonal `clip-path` to create a bar with a triangle effect on `hover`. The drawback here is the poor browser support for [CSS clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

```css
ul {
  width: 120px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 50%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: crimson;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Linear Gradients:**

You can also use `linear-gradient` and pseudo-element combination like in the below snippet but gradients are known to produce jagged edges and are **not really recommended**.

```css
ul {
  width: 120px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, crimson 50%), linear-gradient(to top right, crimson 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 100%, 100% 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}
a:hover {
  background: crimson;
}
a:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Library included just to avoid prefixes so that users with older browser can view -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have border with static width:

```
border-width: 19px 0 19px 11px;
```

but the height of element changes according to number of rows or text size,
so if you update to

```
border-width: 30px 0 30px 11px;
```

it will solve the problem for 2 lines text but will not be good for one line text.
You will have to check with JS heigt of element and the according to it update the :

```
border-width: 'dinamic result from JS'px 0 'dinamic result from JS'px  11px;
```