# Responsive style div with css triangles

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a responsive div with css triangles on each side that has a color the same as my background color, however it breaks when the text gets wraps onto a new line.

Is there any way to code css triangles in a responsive way, where the triangles will grow in height with the text that is wrapping?

[image]

```css
.d-block {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  color: #0769ba;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    border-top: 30px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #fff;
    border-left: 30px solid #0769ba;
  }
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    content: "";
    border-top: 30px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #fff;
    border-right: 30px solid #0769ba;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="d-block">This is a specials block and is 100% wide responsive</div>
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360411/responsive-css-triangle-with-percents-width