# HTML mail - Unable to fix td height

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to make an html mail so I need to use inline CSS. The problem is that I can't figure out why the cell height I set doesn't display as I intended. I've set the % height of the cells like I would them to be, but the result isn't as I expected.

The code is this and as you can see the result is not like I intended because I've set 15% for the header but in the result is obviously not 15% and no matter the value it does not change the result. The same thing happens with the other td:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <table style="table-layout:fixed; width:56%; height:100%;"  border="1" bordercolor=black align=center>
             <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="height:15%; width:100%;" >
                <a href="http://www/">
                  <img src="D:\web_mail\EN_TW1-EE_3D-Logo.pn" width="56%"  alt="Header"/>  </a>
                </th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td  style="border-right-width: 0.5px; border-bottom-width: 1px; height:10%;      width:50%;"  >
                   <img src="D:\web_mail\Halo_4_-_Master_Chief.pn" width="100%"  alt="Patrik" />
                 </td>
                 <td style="border-left-width: 0.5px; border-bottom-width: 1px; height:10%; width:50%;" >
                   <img src="D:\web_mail\08e7d7c88c962186ed557780ab41c628-d65czl9.jp" width="100%"  alt="Alberta" /> 
                 </td>
             </tr>
             
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="height:60%; width:100%;" >
                   <img src="D:\web_mail\08e7d7c88c962186ed557780ab41c628-d65czl9.jp" width="100%" alt="Igor"/>  
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="height:15%; width:100%;" >
                   <img src="D:\web_mail\08e7d7c88c962186ed557780ab41c628-d65czl9.jp" width="56%" alt="Footer"/>  
                </th>
             </tr>          
      </table>   
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j2bcc24o/ Just put it into a JSFiddle and it seems fine?

Comment: i'm afraid it isn't, try to edit the height in the header to 5% and you will notice that it changes nothing. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the image to stretch to the same height and width as the containing boxes, simply add a 100% width and a height equal to the row it is in:

http://jsfiddle.net/j2bcc24o/4/

If you just want the width, go for:

http://jsfiddle.net/j2bcc24o/3/

```
<td style="border-right-width: 0.5px; border-bottom-width: 1px; height:10%; width:50%;">
    <img src="image.png" width="100%" height="10%" alt="Patrik" />
</td>
```

And also don't forget to set html and body to 100% height and width as well as 0 padding and margin:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: ok know i got it, thanks. But why am i having this issue with the right image? i can't figure out why it does not respect the border i set: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1n6x47ygavxs8e/Immagine.png?dl=0

Comment: It may be because your heights are set as a percentage whereas your borders are set as a pixel. Your percentages add up to 100% as it is. Unfortunately you cannot set a border as a percentage, although there is this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages

Comment: nice solution but the problem is that i can't use div but only inline css since i'm trying to create an html mail. No way to get around the problem?

Comment: You could put the images in as backgrounds instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Lukedturnbull/1agb2ccc/1/embedded/result/ and just create clickable space in the TDs for the links

Answer (score 0):

i am not able to understand your problem properly,

assign class to td and set the height

```
<td class="classname">
</td>

.className{
height:20%;
background:red;
}
```

Try the below code

**let me know if you need any help.**

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{ 
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

table{
 table-layout:fixed; 
 width:56%; 
 height:100%; 
 border:1px solid #000;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
}

table th{
 height:15%;
 width:100%;

}
.className{
height:20%;
background:red;
}

td{
 height:50%;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#000;
 width:100%; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table >
 <tr>
  <th colspan="2" >
  <a href="http://www/"> <img src="D:\web_mail\EN_TW1-EE_3D-Logo.pn" width="56%"  alt="Header"/>  </a>
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td >
   <img src="D:\web_mail\Halo_4_-_Master_Chief.pn" width="100%"  alt="Patrik" />
  </td>
  <td >
   <img src="D:\web_mail\08e7d7c88c962186ed557780ab41c628-d65czl9.jp" width="100%"  alt="Alberta" /> 
  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" class="className" >
   <img src="D:\web_mail\08e7d7c88c962186ed557780ab41c628-d65czl9.jp" width="100%" alt="Igor"/>  
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th colspan="2" >
   <img src="D:\web_mail\08e7d7c88c962186ed557780ab41c628-d65czl9.jp" width="56%" alt="Footer"/>  
  </th>
 </tr>          
 </table>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The key is to assign `height: 100%` to the `body` and `html` tags, which you did correctly.  Note that the OP is trying to style HTML for an email, and an embedded style sheet will usually fail in most email clients.

Comment: thanks man, what i would like to do is to set the height of the cell so that they are fixed and i don't need to resize the images to make them fit as i want to. I've chosen some random images to better explain myself: if you look to the result with some images this is what i get. If i want for example to make the footer cell smaller i need to resize the image, but i would like to resize the cell height instead without touching the image height and width properties on the img tag that i'd like to delete. Is this possible?Thanks a lot! https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1n6x47ygavxs8e/Immagine.png?dl=0

Comment: @MarcAudet in fact i added this to the html and body tags but even with this change i can't set for example the footer cell like i would like to. In fact if i set the footer to 10% i don't get what i want because is the width property of the image that seems to control the cell size and i would like to avoid this if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: It still seems to work fine in my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2bcc24o/3/ The Images resize when you resize the browser

Comment: Or if you want to make the height the same size as the table row that it is in, simple add the same percentage height: http://jsfiddle.net/j2bcc24o/4/

Answer (score 0):

Defining height in percentage will not work with td/div, specially for the mailers, need to assign pixel values only.

Comment: But i'd like to keep the same proportions with all the different resolutions. Can't i achieve this?