# <div> with css triangle in the background

Tags: html, css

I want to use css triangle as a shape for a background and I don't know how to do it or if it's possible.

In the end it should be a menu looking like image below.

[image]
http://i59.tinypic.com/4gitzq.png

I have found some ways how to do the shape but I can't fit the text inside...

I just need to know if its possible to get this just by using html and css without images and if the triangle is the right choice.

Under this menu should be another `<div>` with yellow background connected to menu so it will make one shape.

Thank you kindly for all your responses and advices.

PS: fiddle

I'm tring to get "homepage" on the left but I'm lost...

```css
body {
    background-color: 
}

.shape {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.top {
}
.bottom {
 width: 960px;
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 25px;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 color: #f1c40f;
 text-align: right;
 background: #f1c40f; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(4.5deg, #f1c40f 50%, #1c2228 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(50%,#f1c40f), color-stop(50%,#1c2228)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(4.5deg, #f1c40f 50%,#1c2228 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(4.5deg, #f1c40f 50%,#1c2228 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(4.5deg, #f1c40f 50%,#1c2228 50%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(4.5deg, #f1c40f 50%,#1c2228 50%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f1c40f', endColorstr='#1c2228',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.bottom a.special {
    text-align: left;
 padding:100px;
    color: red;
}
.bottom a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover {
 color:#f1c40f;
 background-color:transparent;
 text-decoration:bold;
}
.bottom a, a:active {
 color:#f1c40d;
 background-color:transparent;
 text-decoration:none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hello World!</title> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,400,600,700,200italic,400italic,600italic,700italic&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="bottom">
   <a class="special">Homepage</a>
   <a href="">About</a>
   <a href="">Works</a>
   <a href="">Contact</a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want it to look sharp I suggest drawing it in SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use the Cross browser tecnique of [triangle shape](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/).

It is **cross browser** and not give *pixelate* effect.

Here is a [working demo](http://jsbin.com/xiwerakage/1/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: I'm glad that is the working solution for you! If you are ok with my answer, mark it as the one that solved your issue! :)

Comment: I will :) But, i have one more "but" :D the percentage doesn't work for border-width so I asumed this can't be used with bootstrap am I right?

Comment: Yes, correct, but see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages You can achieve it with JS.