# How do I create three equal list elements with equal guttering between?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the layout in the image where there is a container > Row > Col (Bootstrap) and then three ul li elements. This ul has a border. The li elements need to be fluid. The gutter needs to be equal all around. How can I do this? The red line represents the edge of the wrapper (col-xs-12)

[image]

```
<ul>
    <li>BOX1 </li>
    <li>BOX 2</li>
    <li>BOX 3</li>
</ul>

 ul {border:1px solid #ddd}
 ul li {width:31.333%; min-height:300px;background:blue;float:left; margin-left:1%; margin-right:1%;}
```

However, this gives me more guter between the middle block than I need.

Comment: Please show your markup and your effort. It's a basic requirement of asking a question on SO.

Comment: Solved http://www.bootply.com/RY4LztvxiZ#

Answer (score 1):

- using a flexbox, `display: flex` does this pretty well for you.
- or only set `margin-left` on all 3 elements, and ignore `margin-right`.
- or set `margin-left` and `margin-right`, but have ul:first-child have a
  larger left margin.
- or set `margin-left: .5%`, `margin-right:.5%` on the li, and set extra
  `padding-left` on the ul.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example with `border` in between of all boxes. One problem with `border` is, that it doesn't support percentage, but it also works. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  background:#3E8CB2; 
  float:left; 
  width:calc(100%/3);
  height: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.box:last-child{
  border-right: 4px solid white; 
}

.wrapper{
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  border-right: solid 2px red;
  min-height: 190px;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/cs1vv6Lc/)**