# CSS - Rounded div border in percent

Tags: html, css

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7d24tkrc/7/) rounded `div` element which use percentage values for it's dimensions. then I want to add a border to this element but it's not possible to use percentage for border element!

I have also tried using padding for this purpose but it's not working either because I can't make the padding go round! (it always shapes square or rectangle)

Can you help me add a relatively-sized border to my circle?

I also do not want to use `vw` or such values which use full view port. I want relativity between element's.

```css
.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 10px solid green; /*10px must be percent as it ruins my responsiveness*/
width: 20%;
height: 60%;
left: 40%;
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: I see a black circle with a green border - what exactly are you not able to add?

Comment: border is in `px` value, I want it in `%` value ! @Mobby Motion

Comment: maybe it is possible with pseudo element's like `::after` and `::before` but I couldn't make it !

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, because I'm not really sure what it would mean. A sort of compromise would be to use vw, but this gives it a border relative to the viewport and not the size of the circle.

Comment: percentages are not supported for border properties - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-width-properties

Comment: I know! that's the reason I asked this question here so that maybe someone finds a workaround.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages#13474754

Comment: I have read that post but it didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use outer div with background and control width, height, padding with percentage

```css
.out {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 20%;
height: 35%;
left: 40%;
position: absolute;
background-color: green;
padding:1%
}

.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="circle">
  
   </div>
</div>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZxoMRj

Answer (score 0):

you can fake the border with a radial gradient. It is already expressed in percentages:

```css
.test {
  margin: 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(lightgreen 60%, green 60%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#test1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

#test2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#test3 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test1">
</div>
<div class="test" id="test2">
</div>
<div class="test" id="test3">
</div>
```