# Is there anyway to let border thickness follow parent width/height?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a 300*400 div, which is used to include a table with thick border to create some visual effect:

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:150px;background-color:black;position:relative;">
  <table style="border-top:50px solid red;border-left:50px solid yellow;border-bottom:50px solid green;border-right:50px solid blue;"></table>
</div>
```

but now the table border can have fixed border width only : 100px, but I want the whole table fit into the div by using border, I tried:

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:150px;background-color:black;position:relative;">
      <table style="border-top:50% solid red;border-left:50% solid yellow;border-bottom:50% solid green;border-right:50% solid blue;"></table>
    </div>
```

which set each border width to 50%, but it is not working, Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Stupid question of course, but why a <table>?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:150px;background-color:black;position:relative;">
  <table style="
    border-top: 75px solid red;
    border-left: 100px solid yellow;
    border-bottom: 75px solid green;
    border-right: 100px solid blue;"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS variables for this. Define them in the container div and use them in the div's children.

```html
<div style="--w:200px; --h:150px; width:var(--w); height:var(--h); background-color:black; position:relative;">
  <div style="border-top:calc(var(--h) / 2) solid red; border-left:calc(var(--w) / 2) solid yellow; border-bottom:calc(var(--h) / 2) solid green; border-right:calc(var(--w) / 2) solid blue;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Borders doesnt support percentages.

You can do this only with fixed widths.

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:black;position:relative;">
      <table style="border-top:100px solid red;border-left:100px solid yellow;border-bottom:100px solid green;border-right:100px solid blue;"></table>
    </div>
```

See this link if it helps you 
[How to set border's thickness in percentages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages)