# Is it possible to have a dynamic border-width related to the parent element in css in a responsive spinner?

Tags: html, css

Basically I have been trying to achieve a simple spinner class that can just be attached to any element, including a small button or the whole page.

Other than viewport values I haven't been able to find a way to have a relative border-width.

- If not possible I think the best way would be to separate the loading in 3 classes, small/medium/large, but that adds another layer of complexity.
- Can you use media queries for the parent element width instead of device width? That would solve it I think.
- Or maybe there is a type of css-only spinner that does not rely on border-width that can be used as an ::after element?

The basic test that it needs to go for me would be to :

1. Look good as a class on the whole page
2. Look good as a class on a small button
3. Work in mobile
4. Be able to use in any element by just adding a class without changing its actual content.
5. No Javascript

I'm also open to a better looking loader as I'm a css beginner and have no real clue what I'm doing.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/adfnc5tk/6/

Code of what I have so far :

```
/*Spinner with overlay and no mouse events*/
@keyframes spinner {
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.loading::before {
    position:absolute;
    content : '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.65;
}
.loading:after {
    content: '';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    /*! height: 5rem; */
    margin-top: -12.5%;
    margin-left: -12.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #07d;
    border-bottom-color: #07d;
    animation: spinner .8s ease infinite;
    z-index:3;
    padding-top: calc(12.5% - 1em);
    border-width: 1em;
    padding-bottom: calc(12.5% - 1em);
}
.loading {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: wait;
}

.text-center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Use a SVG instead ? It will scale with your content and you will be able to animate it just the same. If you absolutely want to keep it with a border here is an extra solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages

Comment: I also think it isn't really "ugly". Do it like the big companies, and call it a feature

Comment: I just noticed there is another problem in my original code, I doesn't work inside a button not sure why it goes full page

Comment: @Jake can you show an example on how that works using pseudo elements?

Comment: @Mojimi It's really easier with a svg, here is a quick fork from your JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cr8f1mLt/1/

Comment: @Jake I see but it doesn't work with a pseudo element and just adding a class right? Having to add elements is not what I'm looking for

Comment: You can by setting the svg as a background-image on the pseudo element like so : http://jsfiddle.net/cr8f1mLt/2/

Answer (score 1):

Foe a responsive `border-width` I would use SVG although in the case of SVG it would be a stroke.

```css
/*Spinner with overlay and no mouse events*/
@keyframes spinner {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.loading::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.loading {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: wait;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 40vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  animation: spinner .8s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading text-center">
<h1>
  Resize this window to see it in action !
</h1>
<h3>
But if you reduce the width too much it gets ugly :(
</h3>
<button>
 You can't click me!
</button>

</div>
  <svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
    <circle r="46" fill="none" stroke="#07d" stroke-width="7" stroke-dasharray="72.26" stroke-dashoffset="-36.13" />
  </svg>
```

In the CSS I'm using width: `width:40vmin;` but if you need to use it on a button you may want to change this.

Answer (score 0):

With some *less well supported* properties like `conical-gradient` and `mask-image` this is possible.

Chrome only (probably)

```css
body {
  background: lightgreen;
}

div.conic-gradient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.conic-gradient:after {
  content: "";
  background: conic-gradient(
    blue 25%,
    transparent 0 50%,
    blue 0 75%,
    transparent 75%
  );
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="conic-gradient"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use font size to scale the spinner. And inherit the font-size from parent;

```css
.loading {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.loading:after {
  animation: spinAround .5s infinite linear;
  border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
  border-radius: 290486px;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}

.loading:after {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 4;
}

.loading:after {
    font-size: inherit;
}

@keyframes spinAround {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
Resize this window to see it in action !
</div>
```