# How to create the illusion of a 100% width div that is actually fixed width (with bg color)

Tags: css

My body's bg color is white and I have this div:

```
<div style="max-width:1140px;margin:0 auto;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.50)">
    Lorum ipsum example
</div>
```

The div is horizontally centered and has a bg color black w/50% transparency.

I want to simulate the black bg color w/50% transparency to the left and the right of the div for visitors with screen resolutions larger than 1140w *without wrapping it in a container div*, if that's even possible. I think it might not be possible.

I thought about borders, but [you can't set border widths in percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474754/how-to-set-borders-thickness-in-percentages).

Edit: [Here is a fiddle which should paint a clear picture of what I'm after](https://jsfiddle.net/e4mqs8od/)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve be more specific or illustrate what you wanted with a image

Comment: @Rana See fiddle link above

Comment: You could color the `body` in grey and to leave the fixed width div in the center of it.

Comment: @Azu It's a good suggestion, but it won't work for me in this case

Comment: Why a wrapper is a problem? Another idea is to use `:before` and `:after` but I am not sure if it's going to work out in the way you like.

Comment: from the duplicate simply make both box-shadow color and background color the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `::after` or `::before` to achieve the same as needed

> This is for demo only you can change styles according to need

```css
.orignDiv {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .50)
}

.orignDiv::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="orignDiv">
  Lorum ipsum example
</div>
```

Also you can achieve by extra `div` which is not wrapped around the main `div`

```css
.orignDiv {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .50)
}

.withoutWrap {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(20, 0, 0, .50);
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  top: -20px
}
```

```html
<div class="orignDiv">
  Lorum ipsum example
</div>
<div class="withoutWrap"></div>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't because of the extra div

Comment: Have changes the answer with `::after` and `::before` see if that what you want @Jeff

Comment: You can upvote the answer too if it helped your problem : )